# Manipulating web page elements in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, forms, webbrowser-control

I'm currently working on an application where I need to do some manipulation of forms on websites. The current implementation is done in WPF with a WebBrowser control. I can successfully fill in fields and click buttons on the sites.

I would really like to implement the same functionality in Silverlight but it seems like the WebBrowser is severely crippled and I cant access the Document to fill anything in. Is there any way to do this?

It would be even better if I could just have an iframe and manipulate the contents from a Silverlight application, but I'm not sure if this is possible either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manipulate HTML DOM as well as invoke JS functions from Silverlight using the [HtmlPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.browser.htmlpage%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class and [HtmlElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.aspx) objects.